# Cannot find component with identifier "acinfo" referenced from "account"

Tags: long-integer

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:panelGroup id="acinfo">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>#{masterdata['bank.account.info']}</legend>

            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%">#{masterdata['bank.account.name']}</td>
                    <td width="30%"><h:inputText
                            value="#{bankAccountBean.accountBank.name}" style="width:98%"
                            class="validate[required] text-input" tabindex="1" /></td>
                    <td width="20%">#{masterdata['bank.account.branch.name']}</td>
                    <td width="30%"><h:inputText
                            value="#{bankAccountBean.accountBank.namech}" style="width:98%"
                            class="validate[required] text-input" tabindex="6" /></td>
                </tr>
                ...............
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> #{masterdata['bank.branch.list']} </legend>
        <p:dataTable id="account" value="#{bankAccountBean.listbankAccount}"
            var="baccount" selection="#{bankAccountBean.accountBank}"
            selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{baccount.makhtaikhoan}"
            scrollable="true" scrollWidth="1088" scrollHeight="250"
            style="text-align: left;">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="acinfo" />
            <p:column headerText="#{masterdata['bank.branch.name']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{baccount.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{masterdata['bank.account.branch.name']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{baccount.namech}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{masterdata['bank.account.code']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{baccount.makhtaikhoan}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{masterdata['bank.account.number']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{baccount.mataikhoan}" />
            </p:column>
        ...........

        </p:dataTable>
    </fieldset>
</ui:define>
```

**main template**

```
<h:form id="formbutton" prependId="false">

    <div id="cont" class="contentform" style="padding-top: 16px;">
        <div style="text-align: left; height: 18px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />

        </div>
        <div>
            <ui:insert name="content">Content Form</ui:insert>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="jSplash"></div>
</h:form>
```

**Error**

```
[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Error Rendering View[/masterdata/CM_Bank_Account.xhtml]: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "acinfo" referenced from "account".
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try adding a colon in front of it so it becomes `update=":acinfo"` and see if that works.

If not, then if you take the update out (so the page loads) and find the acinfo panelGroup on the page, is its ID still acinfo?  I see you have `prependId` set to false in your main template, but it's probably wise to double-check.  If it's different, try setting it to that instead (or with a colon in front of it.)

If both of those fail, perhaps try setting `prependId` on formbutton to true, then `update=":formbutton:acinfo"`?